# Advanced root problems

Tags: rooting

I am having problems rooting my device after a friend unrooted it.
Now, if this was a pure simple case, it'd already be solved, but:

1. I can only used soft-roots, like Kingo root.
2. My "friend" decided to change my android version number and model number before the unroot, making these soft-roots not work.
3. My device will cease to function if I SIM unlock and bootload. Don't know why.

Please help. I really want to sell my device, but cannot.

-EDIT-
Well, FTP failed, as did using ADB to pull, edit, and push the file back on.

Comment: You can always restore your device to factory state. Just tell which one: IBM/370 by any chance?

Comment: I already tried resetting the settings, got nothing. I cannot simply reset; my data is a vital asset to my deep-web research. Could I try FTP? And what do you mean by IBM/370? I am using Sony Xperia E C1505

Comment: what's the device model ? and the android version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow managed to get king root to work...

King root was the original rooting tools I used, and after the change in the build.prop it stopped working. It seems be fine now, tough.